# How do I make a beep function using SDL?

Tags: c, audio, sdl

I want to make my SDL program sound a simple beep at a certain frequency. How do I go about doing that?

I've found a [tutorial](http://www.dgames.org/beep-sound-with-sdl/) that writes to SDL's sound buffer or so, but it doesn't seem to work. (I'm using OSX "Snow Leopard")

Comment: Intrigued! Might have a go at this on the weekend.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you hear any sound at all? Is there any useful information returned by SDL_GetError? Have you tried asking on the [SDL forums](http://forums.libsdl.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial's code forgets to initialize `Beeper::v` and `generateSamples` does not work with random values of v. Try to add the line `v=0;` to `Beeper::Beeper()`